# How to send a post request inside of a shopware 6 controller?

Tags: shopware

Which is the correct way to send a post request inside of a Shopware 6 controller to another shopware controller(not external site, same shop) by using default shopware methods.

I know that curl or file get contents can be used, but are there any default methods?

Answer (score 1):

You can forward the request to another controller like this. You should never to a 'real' POST request to another internal controller, this will add a lot of HTTP overhead and slow down your webshop.

The first parameter is the name/function of the ohter controller you want to call, the second parameter is a named array of the parameters of the other controller.

```
public function originalController($name)
{
    $response = $this->forward('App\Controller\OtherController::fancy', [
        'name'  => $name,
        'color' => 'green',
    ]);

    // ... further modify the response or return it directly

    return $response;
}
```

Source: https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/forwarding.html